# Stop displaying recent files list in File Explorer

Tags: lumia, windows-10-mobile, file-explorer

In Windows Phone 10, the File Explorer is displaying recently Opened files similarly in Windows 10 Desktop File Explorer. A typical File Explorer is as below (here the recent files are not visible)

[image: Windows Phone 10 File Explorer View]

In Windows 10 Desktop there is an option to disable the same. Is there any such option available for Windows Phone also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cant do that on phone.

Comment: Sad, but yes. can't do.